# Does Rota's basis conjecture over some fixed field imply Rota's basis conjecture?

Tags: co.combinatorics

Is [Rota's basis conjecture](https://gowers.wordpress.com/2017/02/24/timothy-chow-starts-polymath12/) implied by the same statement restricted to vector spaces over a fixed field (say $\mathbb{R}$, or even $\mathbb{Z}_2$)?